# This Javascript function keeps looping, how can i make it run once?

Tags: javascript, loops

The code is meant to animated some text in a typing fashion. I want it to run once, but it keeps looping through the area of sentences. How would i go about stopping it looping through.  The top of the code gathers the value of a input and puts into the array, this all works fine. It is just the looping i am having issues with.

```
var yourWord = document.getElementById("myText").value;

var yourtext = "I took the word " + yourWord + "...";


var infomation = [yourtext,
        'I looked at the most relevant news article relating to it...',
        'And created this piece of art from the words in the article! '
    ],

    part,

    i = 0,
    offset = 0,
    pollyLen = Polly.length,
    forwards = true,
    skip_count = 0,
    skip_delay = 5,
    speed = 100;

var wordflick = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (forwards) {
            if (offset >= infomation[i].length) {
                ++skip_count;
                if (skip_count == skip_delay) {
                    forwards = false;
                    skip_count = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (offset == 0) {
                forwards = true;
                i++;
                offset = 0;
                if (i >= pollyLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        part = infomation[i].substr(0, offset);
        if (skip_count == 0) {
            if (forwards) {
                offset++;
            } else {
                offset--;
            }
        }
        $('#pollyInfo').text(part);
    }, speed);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    wordflick();
});
```

Comment: What looping specifically? I mean, there's the setInterval, which repeats, but that's kind of the point of it. I don't see any other loops.

Comment: If you don't want it to loop, don't use `setInterval()`. Just execute the code once, and call the function whenever you want to execute it again.

Comment: The array of sentences keeps looping. I want it to loop through them once then stop.

Comment: Assign the result of `setInterval` to a variable. When you reach the end of the array, call `clearInterval(thatVariable)`

Comment: Edit the question to add clarification, don't just put it in comments.

Comment: What is setInterval doing to the code currently?

Comment: I also don't really understand what you mean by make setInterval as a variable?

Comment: The return value of setInterval is a value you can use to clear (i.e., stop) that interval from running.

Comment: The setInterval Function in the code though controls the speed that the sentences type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the line:

```
setInterval(function () {
```

into:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
```

and then clear the interval where you are setting i=0;

```
if (i >= pollyLen) {
                    i = 0;
}
```

to:

```
if (i >= pollyLen) {
                    i = 0;
                    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

This should do the job!

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. You have been incredibly helpful